# Weighted randomization based on runtime data in System Verilog

Tags: constraints, system-verilog, verification, hdl, random-seed

Is there a way to do weighted randomization in System Verilog based on runtime data. Say, I have a queue of integers and a queue of weights (unsigned integers) and wish to select a random integer from the first queue as per the weights in the second queue.

```
int data[$] = '{10, 20, 30};
uint_t weights[$] = '{100, 200, 300};
```

Any random construct expects the weights hardcoded as in

```
constraint range { Var dist { [0:1] := 50 , [2:7] := 50 }; }
```

But in my case, I need to pick an element from an unknown number of elements.

PS: Assume the number of elements and weights will be the same always.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `dist` constraint only lets you choose from a fixed number of values.

Two approaches I can think of are

1. Push each data value into a queue using the weight as a repetition count. In your example, you wind up with a queue of 600 values. Randomly pick an index into the queue. The selected element has the distribution you want. An example is posted [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/can-i-use-dynamic-array-set-distribution#reply-44653).
2. Create an array of ranges for each weight. For your example the array would be `uint_t ranges[][2]'{{0,99},{100,299},{300,599}}`. Then you could do the following in a constraint

   `index inside {[0:weights.sum()-1]};
   foreach (data[ii])
       index inside {[ranges[ii][0]:ranges[ii][1]} -> value == date[ii];`

Comment: Thank you dave_59, for confirming. I think creating such huge arrays would be time-consuming and wastage of memory, I think implementing a custom weighted random function based on $urandom/$urandom_range would be optimal. What do you think?